# Adding Horizontal or Vertical Lines in a Scatterplot using Taipy

Tags: python, user-interface, taipy

I was creating a scatterplot using Taipy and wanted to know the best way to include horizontal or vertical lines on the plot. In Plotly, there is a convenient function called `fig.add_vline()` to add vertical lines to a scatterplot. However, I need help finding a direct equivalent function in Taipy to achieve the same result.

## Expected Behavior:

It would want to know if adding horizontal or vertical lines to a scatterplot is possible. This feature would allow users to easily visualize specific reference lines or thresholds in their scatterplots, aiding in data analysis and interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a column with constant values is the most straightforward way. You can also do it by customizing the layout of the chart.

Here is the code for your question:

```py
from taipy import Gui

data = {
  "x": [2, 3.5, 6],
  "y": [1, 1.5, 1],
}

layout = {
  "shapes": [
    #line vertical
    {
      "type": 'line',
      "x0": 1, "y0": 0, "x1": 1, "y1": 2,
      "line": {
        "color": 'rgb(55, 128, 191)',
      }
    },
    #Line Horizontal
    {
      "type": 'line',
      "x0": 2, "y0": 2, "x1": 5, "y1": 2,
      "line": {
        "color": 'rgb(50, 171, 96)',
        "dash": 'dashdot'
      }
    },
    #Line Diagonal
    {
      "type": 'line',
      "x0": 4, "y0": 0, "x1": 6, "y1": 2,
      "line": {
        "color": 'rgb(128, 0, 128)',
        "dash": 'dot'
      }
    }
  ]
}


md = "<|{data}|chart|x=x|y=y|layout={layout}|>"

Gui(md).run()
```

[image]